# install wine on ubuntu 20.04 LTS fails with unknown ppa

Tags: wine, ppa

I have tried several installs of wine Ubuntu 20.04 and they fail at the same point with the following:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                              
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fprint/ubuntu focal InRelease                    
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease         
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fprint/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fprint/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
```

apt-secure(8) says something about accepting ppa's with no Release files but the specific steps are not specified.
Any suggestions as to how to proceed will be appreciated.

Comment: I opened up the URL on the PPA with error & support was last offered in 18.04/bionic, so security checks (which are your responsibility for 3rd party sources/PPAs; https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint) should have flagged that a PPA that ceased being maintained in 2018-April was a potential security risk, let alone being unsuitable for a focal/20.04 system.

Comment: The PPA giving the error has nothing to do with the attempts at installing wine. Just remove it as mentioned in the link above.